# Can Rickshaw.graph() create the chart at specific co-ordinate?

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

If I have an existing SVG element & I want the chart created by
Rickshaw.graph() to be inserted at a certain (x,y) co-ordinate
in the (previously)existing SVG element, is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

SVG Elements are elements, so add a `<svg:g>` to your svg style it with appropriate `transform`s, and tell rickshaw to render into it by passing it as `element` to the `Rickshaw.Graph` constructor.